# How to know the application cache is cleared in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

As soon as my application is installed in any android mobile, The owner of the application will receive a text message from the mobile where application is installed. Message is sent in the first installation of the app. Messages are not sent when it is run more than once.My app  will send sms for the first installation and thats working fine,But when i clear the application cache , it must not send the sms, Since its already installed. It will clear the cache and the message is sent again.Please help me in getting code . Hope ill get proper solution. Below i ve posted the code.

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)) {

    //send_message_function(); 

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);

     editor.commit();
    }
```

The code will send message for the first installation of app.But it also sends message while the cache is cleared. But i want a code which must not send sms when the cache is cleared, and sends only for the first installation of app...Please help me out.

Comment: hi , you are sending sms using webservice or default device message ?

Comment: Default device message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [This Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744104/whats-the-difference-between-clear-cache-clear-data-in-android-settings) i would like to suggest store in local database and using that decide your further process.

`Clear Cache` will remove all data and it just like temporary storage its not longer useful for data access.

Hope you got the concept and implement that way.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am clear about the clear cache concepts. Sorry If my questions was hard to understand. What I want is like : I want to detect or know when the clear cache button is clicked to clear my application cache.

Comment: @Kay i am always checking the difference between older and update. even i have two reject and 1 copy content as i feel.what's the issue if i approve 10 or more then 10 ?